# Select on ListView items and show users info from DB another activity in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-database

I want show some of users info in `listview` items and when click on items, show full users info into another activity (such as pass data from database to other activity). I use `SQLiteDataBase` to save users information. But I do not know how to do?! 
For example : when click on user 5 , show user's 5 full information in other activity!

**Attention :** Please do not disappoint me and don't give me negative points.
I searched online but could not find a suitable method for this I raised in my question here.Please guide me because I am amateur.

**Main Page Code :**

```
public class MainPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    private UserDbHelper userDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private ListDataAdapter listDataAdapter;
    private DataProvider dataProvider;
    private TextView dataCount_tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page);

        userDbHelper = new UserDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
        sqLiteDatabase = userDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = userDbHelper.getUserInfo(sqLiteDatabase);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_row_layout);
        listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String name, family, password, phone, email;
                name = cursor.getString(0);
                family = cursor.getString(1);
                password = cursor.getString(2);
                phone = cursor.getString(3);
                email = cursor.getString(4);
                dataProvider = new DataProvider(name, family, password, phone, email);
                listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                /// Code ... ?!!!
            }
        });

        dataCount_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_dataCount_text);
        dataCount_tv.setText("Count of Data : " + listDataAdapter.getCount());
    }

    public void search_button(View view){

        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SearchPage.class));
    }
}
```

**Users Page Code :**

```
public class UserPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView user_name_tv, user_family_tv, user_phone_tv, user_email_tv;
    private FloatingActionButton user_delete_btn, user_edit_btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user_page);

        user_name_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_info_name);
        user_family_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_info_family);
        user_phone_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_phone_text);
        user_email_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_email_text);


    }
}
```

**ListView Adapter Code :**

```
public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    List list = new ArrayList();

    public ListDataAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    static class LayoutHandler {

        TextView NAME, FAMILY, PASSWORD, PHONE, EMAIL;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Object object) {
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
        if (row == null) {

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, parent, false);
            layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
            layoutHandler.NAME = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_user_name);
            layoutHandler.FAMILY = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_user_family);
            layoutHandler.PASSWORD = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_user_password);
            layoutHandler.PHONE = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_user_phone);
            layoutHandler.EMAIL = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_user_email);
            row.setTag(layoutHandler);

        } else {

            layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler) row.getTag();
        }
        DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider) this.getItem(position);
        layoutHandler.NAME.setText(dataProvider.getName());
        layoutHandler.FAMILY.setText(dataProvider.getFamily());
        layoutHandler.PASSWORD.setText(dataProvider.getPassword());
        layoutHandler.PHONE.setText(dataProvider.getPhone());
        layoutHandler.EMAIL.setText(dataProvider.getEmail());

        return row;
    }
}
```

**SQLiteOpenHelper Code :**

```
public class UserDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UserInfoDB.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + UserContract.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME + "(" +
            UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_NAME + " TEXT," +
            UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_FAMILY + " TEXT," +
            UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT," +
            UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_PHONE + " TEXT," +
            UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_EMAIL + " TEXT);";

    public UserDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATION : ", "Database Create / Open...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATION : ", "Table Create...");
    }


    public void AddUserInfo(String name, String family, String password, String phone, String email, SQLiteDatabase db) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_FAMILY, family);
        contentValues.put(UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_PASSWORD, password);
        contentValues.put(UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_PHONE, phone);
        contentValues.put(UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_EMAIL, email);

        db.insert(UserContract.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATION : ", "One row inserted...");
    }

    public Cursor getUserInfo(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        Cursor cursor;
        String[] projections = {UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_NAME, UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_FAMILY,
                UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_PASSWORD, UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_PHONE,
                UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_EMAIL};
        String list_sort = UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_ID + " DESC";

        cursor = db.query(UserContract.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME, projections, null, null, null, null, list_sort);
        return cursor;
    }

    public Cursor getContacts(String user_name, SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String[] projections = {UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_FAMILY, UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_PASSWORD,
                UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_PHONE, UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_EMAIL};
        String selection = UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_NAME + " LIKE ?";
        String[] selection_args = {user_name};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(UserContract.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME, projections, selection, selection_args, null, null, null);

        return cursor;
    }

    public Boolean login(String username, String password, SQLiteDatabase db) throws SQLException {

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + UserContract.NewUserInfo.TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_NAME + "=? AND " +
                UserContract.NewUserInfo.USER_PASSWORD + "=?", new String[]{username, password});

        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

**DataProvider class code :**

```
public class DataProvider {

    private String name, family, password, phone, email;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getFamily() {
        return family;
    }

    public void setFamily(String family) {
        this.family = family;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public DataProvider(String name, String family, String password, String phone, String email) {

        this.name = name;
        this.family = family;
        this.password = password;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;

    }

}
```

Please help me, because i need to this tutorial. tnx for all dears <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your dataprovider object class

```
public class DataProvider implements Serializable {

private String name, family, password, phone, email;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getFamily() {
    return family;
}

public void setFamily(String family) {
    this.family = family;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public DataProvider(String name, String family, String password, String phone, String email) {

    this.name = name;
    this.family = family;
    this.password = password;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.email = email;

}
}
```

and onItemclick method

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           DataProvider dataprovider = (DataProvider)listDataadapter.getItem(position);
           Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
           bundle.putSerializable("anyname",dataprovider);
           Intent intent = new Intent(MainPage.this,yoursecondactivity.class); 
           intent.putExtras(bundle);
          startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

on second activity you need to get this parameter using

getIntent().getExtras();

and check if whether it is null or not if not null then stored it in dataprovider object

Comment: very very thanks for your help. can you send me Second Activity code? please. or send you my project (this is test project and easy for Analysis codes) and you edit this project and send to me ? please, i really need this tutorial :(

Comment: in your second activity do like this DataProvider dataprovider = (DataProvider) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("anyname");

Comment: how to set this : and check if whether it is null or not if not null then stored it in dataprovider object . please send me this code? thanks

Comment: On second activity write the code as H4SN says.... inside oncreate method after getting dataprovider object ..you just need to get data from dataprovider object

Comment: @DharmeshDhameliya, can you send me Second Activity codes such as above codes? thanks

Comment: @H4SN, can you send me Second Activity codes such as above codes? thanks

Comment: @DharmeshDhameliya, how to set datas (from database) and set text to TextView in second activity?

Comment: @DharmeshDhameliya, i find it. your way is very easy. thaaaaaaaaaanks maaaaaaaaaaaaaan <3. you are very good. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to pass the user information from your ListActivity to the ProfileACtivity. There are two ways to achieve this:

1. Using Parceable Model

Create a parceable model. Lets call it UserModel. Android Studio helps in making a class Parceable. You simply need to make UserModel implement Parceable interface. 
(What is a Parceable interface -> It helps in passing objects from one component to another. You can find more information online)

Now pass this in the Intent using the following code

```
intent.putExtra("user", myUserModel);
```

In your Profile activity you can obtain this object using:

```
UserModel userModel = getIntent().getExtra("user");
//Now populate your views using the model you just obtained from the intent
```

2. Passing the id to the activity and obtaining the complete UserModel from the database in the ProfileACtivity:

   intent.putExtra("id", id);

ProfileActivity:

```
int id = getIntent().getExtra("id");

UserModel userModel = mMySQLiteHelper.getUserData(id);
//Populate your views using this model.
```

Please note that I haven't gone through your code yet. But I think you can easily accommodate either of these approaches in your code to achieve the same.

Let me know if you need more help with this.